# Equality for two simple expressions with only bitwise operations

Tags: algorithm, sha1

Given the following two functions in C language:

```
int f(int x, int y, int z) {
    return (x & y) | ((~x) & z);
}

int g(int x, int y, int z) {
    return z ^ (x & (y ^ z));
}
```

The results of the two functions are equal for any valid integer.

I just wonder the mathematics between the two expressions.

I've first seen the expression for function f in the SHA-1 algorithm on wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha1

In the "SHA-1 pseudocode" part, inside the Main loop:

```
if 0 ≤ i ≤ 19 then
        f = (b and c) or ((not b) and d)
        k = 0x5A827999
...
```

In some open source implementation, it uses the form in function g: z ^ (x & (y ^ z)).

I write a program and iterate all the possible values for x, y, z, and all the results are equal.

How to deduce the form

```
(x & y) | ((~x) & z)
```

to the form

```
z ^ (x & (y ^ z))
```

in mathematics? Not just only proving the equality.

Comment: if they're equal, then you can figure it out yoruself with basic algebra: Write both out: `expression1 = expression2` and then reduce them the simplest possible form. If they end up at `0 = 0`, they're equal

Comment: Are you even sure they're equivalent for signed (i.e. negative) values, and that this isn't platform-dependent?

Comment: @RakibulHasan All operations here are perfectly represented by Boolean arithmetic performed in parallel for each bit of the operands. No artifacts.

Comment: Do you need the workings? Wolfram Alpha can [reduce your xor function to DNF](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z+XOR+%28x+and+%28y+XOR+z%29%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map). Given the [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e3s35b52udn&mail=1) for `z ^ (x & (y ^ z))`, the Karnaugh map is:

[image: Karnaugh Map]

As can be seen, you can make two groups from the diagram, giving you `(x & y) | (~x & z)`

Comment: The diagram you given and Karnaugh Map on wikipedia are very helpful. I understand it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Since bitwise operations are equivalent to boolean operations on the individual bits, you can prove the equivalence simply by enumerating the eight assignments of the `{x, y, z}` three-tuples.

Fill out the truth tables for each of these two functions, and then compare the eight positions to each other. If all eight positions match, the two functions are equivalent; otherwise, the functions are different.

You do not need to do it manually either: plug in both functions in three nested loops that give `x`, `y`, and `z` values from zero to one, inclusive, and compare the results of invoking `f(x,y,z)` to `g(x,y,z)`.

Comment: Can you help with some kind of transformation from one to the other? I didn't describe my purpose clearly before. How to deduce from one form to the other, not just prove it?